# SELECT count(*) IN SELECT

Tags: sql

How can `SELECT count(*) IN SELECT`

I have select:

```
SELECT t1.idTab1 
FROM table1 t1, (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.idTab1 = t1.idTab1) 
WHERE t1.idTab1 <= 3
```

My sample data is:

Table1:

```
idTab1
1
2
3
```

Table2:

```
Tab2CountIdTab1
10
200
30
```

And in result I want to have:

```
idTab1 Tab2CountIdTab1 
1      10
2      200
3      30
```

Comment: Is there an id in the second table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT t1.idTab1,
       (SELECT count(*) 
          FROM table2 t2 
         WHERE t2.idTab1 = t1.idTab1) as Tab2CountIdTab1
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.idTab1 <= 3;
```